# from a pickle file, restoring data in python

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I'm having some problems with restoring the pose from a dictionary in Python. I just created a dictionary that has the data from an object and I saved this dictionary in a pickle file.

Now I want to grab all the data from this pickle file and restore it to another object. 
Can you advise me what is the best way?

This is my save_pose function:

```
def save_pose () :

     output = open('pose_dictionary.pkl', 'wb')
     pickle.dump(grab_pose(cmds.ls(selection=1), True), output)
     output.close()

     dict_file = open('pose_dictionary.pkl', 'rb')           
     dict_pkld = pickle.load(dict_file)
     dict_file.close()


     print dict_pkld
```

i just saved a dictionary in a pickle file, so when a print the dict_pkld it returns this

```
{u'left_pCube1_control': {u'translateX': {'value': 0.0, 'key': False}, u'translateY': {'value': 0.0, 'key': False}, u'translateZ': {'value': 0.0, 'key': False}, u'scaleX': {'value': 4.1730065104412066, 'key': {'outTangent': u'auto', 'inTangent': u'auto', 'inAngle': 0.0, 'outAngle': 0.0}}, u'scaleY': {'value': 4.1730065104412066, 'key': {'outTangent': u'auto', 'inTangent': u'auto', 'inAngle': 0.0, 'outAngle': 0.0}}, u'visibility': {'value': True, 'key': False}, u'rotateX': {'value': 0.0, 'key': False}, u'rotateY': {'value': 0.0, 'key': False}, u'rotateZ': {'value': 0.0, 'key': False}, u'scaleZ': {'value': 4.1730065104412066, 'key': {'outTangent': u'auto', 'inTangent': u'auto', 'inAngle': 0.0, 'outAngle': 0.0}}}
```

I want now restore these data from this file to an object.

Comment: Is this just a test function, to verify that what `grab_pose()` returns is equivalent to the `dict_pkld` you get back at the end? And is the problem that they aren't equivalent? If so, can you give us some sample data (ideally just a dict, so we don't even need `grab_pose` at all) to test it?

Comment: `dict_pkld` contains exactly the data you want. your question is very unclear.

Comment: yes , it contains the data , but i don't know how i can restore to an other object

Comment: sorry for my poor english.

Comment: The dict containing the data already _is_ another object. What else do you want to do with it? Is there some other kind of object you want to make out of it? If so, what kind? Do you want to do the exact opposite of what `grab_pose` does? Then you'll have to show use `grab_pose` and/or describe what it does.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to communicate what you want to say in English, do it in code. Show us the code you have, the skeleton for the code you don't know how to write, the input data, and the output data you want.

Comment: Do you want to *copy* the dictionary? do you want to make another variable hold it? do you want to load it on another program?

Answer (score 0):

> i'm having some problems with restoring the pose from a dictionary in
>   Python

What problems exactly... If I had to guess I'd say that there is something wrong with your `grab_pose` function.

When I run the following script I don't get any errors.

```
import pickle

output = open('pose_dictionary.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump({"test":1}, output)
output.close()

dict_file = open('pose_dictionary.pkl', 'rb')           
dict_pkld = pickle.load(dict_file)
dict_file.close()

print dict_pkld
```

Comment: can you update your question with that comment along with the code for the object you want to restore? I imagine you will be able to just pass the dict to that object (assuming the object uses kwargs in its init declaration).

Answer (score -1):

[Docs on `pickle.load`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

> Read a string from the open file object file and interpret it as a pickle data stream, reconstructing and returning the original object hierarchy.

In your function you both save and restore the object. you should split these operations (and use `with`):

```
filename = 'pose_dictionary.pkl'

def save_pose(data):
     with open(filename , 'wb') as output:
         pickle.dump(data, output)

def restore_pose():
     with open(filename , 'rb') as dict_file:
         return pickle.load(dict_file)

data = grab_pose(cmds.ls(selection=1), True) #assumption, based on your code
save_pose(data)
#... 
data = restore_pose()
```